# ggplot2 plotmath: using bquote to add (<=) sign in label error

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to add a less than or equal sign "<=" label in my ggplot but keep getting the error:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid mathematical annotation
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
lower_limit <- 15

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
geom_point() + 
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(lower_limit, 35), 
breaks = c(lower_limit, 25, 35), 
labels = c(bquote(""<= .(lower_limit)), "25", "35"))
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an expression vector as labels, and your code gives a list.  Use `as.expression()` to convert it:

```r
library(ggplot2)

lower_limit <- 15

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(lower_limit, 35), 
                     breaks = c(lower_limit, 25, 35), 
                     labels = as.expression(c(bquote("" <= .(lower_limit)), "25", "35")))
#> Warning: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below update

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(lower_limit, 35), 
                     breaks = c(lower_limit, 25, 35),
                     labels = c(str_glue('<={lower_limit}'),'25','35'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

Comment: This doesn't render the less than equal sign correctly

Comment: isn't it as displayed the expected `<=`